# Dynamically bind an Edit Box in a custom control to a managed bean

Tags: xpages, managed-bean, editbox

I've read a number of excellent posts and articles about dynamically binding fields in a custom control, but they have all assumed a document data source.

I want to allow the possibility of a managed bean data source. I tried setting the property type to `com.ibm.xsp.model.DataSource` or `com.ibm.xsp.extlib.model.ObjectDataSource` and neither of those work with the following xml:

```
<xp:inputText
    id="input"
    value="${compositeData.dsn[compositeData.fieldName]}"
>
</xp:inputText>
```

Where the control is used I have passed in custom data like so:

```
<xc:input
    dsn="#{issue}"
    fieldName="Database"
>
</xc:input>
```

For my test purpose, I have a managed bean named `issue` and I called my field `Database`. I would normally bind to `#{issue.Database}` but I can't figure out how to do that dynamically. Ideally, I would like to support document data sources as well, but if I can't do both then I need to bind to the managed bean.

Edit: The problem seems to be the array-notation. If I hardcode my value to `#{issue.Database}` it works but if I hardcode it to `#{issue[Database]}` it fails. So the question is if there is an alternative representation of dot-notation. I don't have time today, but I wonder if instead of separating dsn and fieldName if I just passed #{issue} into dsn and used that as my data binding would that work? I will try that when I get a chance.

Edit2: As it appears the problem may be related to the bean I'm using, I'll post the code for that here.

**AbstractMapModel**

```
public abstract class AbstractMapModel implements Serializable, DataObject {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Map<Object, Object> values;

    public Class<?> getType(final Object key) {
        Class<?> result = null;
        if (getValues().containsKey(key)) {
            Object value = getValues().get(key);
            if (value != null) {
                result = value.getClass();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    protected Map<Object, Object> getValues() {
        if (values == null) {
            values = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
        }
        return values;
    }

    public Object getValue(final Object key) {
        return getValues().get(key);
    }

    public boolean isReadOnly(final Object key) {
        return false;
    }

    public void setValue(final Object key, final Object value) {
        getValues().put(key, value);
    }
}
```

**AbstractDocumentMapModel**

```
public abstract class AbstractDocumentMapModel extends AbstractMapModel {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String unid;

public AbstractDocumentMapModel() {
    String documentId = ExtLibUtil.readParameter(FacesContext
            .getCurrentInstance(), "id");
    if (StringUtil.isNotEmpty(documentId)) {
        load(documentId);
    }
}

protected abstract String getFormName();

public String getUnid() {
    return unid;
}

public void setUnid(String unid) {
    this.unid = unid;
}

public void load(final String unid) {
    setUnid(unid);
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        if (StringUtil.isNotEmpty(getUnid())) {
            doc = ExtLibUtil.getCurrentDatabase().getDocumentByUNID(
                    getUnid());
            DominoDocument wrappedDoc = DominoDocument.wrap(doc
                    .getParentDatabase().getFilePath(), // databaseName
                    doc, // Document
                    null, // computeWithForm
                    null, // concurrencyMode
                    false, // allowDeleteDocs
                    null, // saveLinksAs
                    null // webQuerySaveAgent
                    );
            for (Object eachItem : doc.getItems()) {
                if (eachItem instanceof Item) {
                    Item item = (Item) eachItem;
                    String itemName = item.getName();
                    if (!("$UpdatedBy".equalsIgnoreCase(itemName) || "$Revisions"
                            .equalsIgnoreCase(itemName))) {
                        setValue(item.getName(), wrappedDoc.getValue(item
                                .getName()));
                    }
                    DominoUtil.incinerate(eachItem);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        DominoUtil.incinerate(doc);
    }
}

protected boolean postSave() {
    return true;
}

protected boolean querySave() {
    return true;
}

public boolean save() {
    boolean result = false;
    if (querySave()) {
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            if (StringUtil.isEmpty(getUnid())) {
                doc = ExtLibUtil.getCurrentDatabase().createDocument();
                setUnid(doc.getUniversalID());
                doc.replaceItemValue("Form", getFormName());
            } else {
                doc = ExtLibUtil.getCurrentDatabase().getDocumentByUNID(
                        getUnid());
            }
            for (Entry<Object, Object> entry : getValues().entrySet()) {
                String itemName = entry.getKey().toString();
                doc.replaceItemValue(itemName, DominoUtil
                        .toDominoFriendly(entry.getValue()));
            }
            if (doc.save()) {
                result = postSave();
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            DominoUtil.incinerate(doc);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

**IssueModel**

```
public class IssueModel extends AbstractDocumentMapModel implements
    Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
protected String getFormName() {
    return "frmIssue";
}

@Override
protected boolean querySave() {
    return super.querySave();
}

@Override
public boolean isReadOnly(final Object key) {
    boolean result = super.isReadOnly(key);
    /**
     * Implement read only logic here as follows
     * 
     * if ("jobTitle".equalsIgnoreCase((String) key)) { if
     * (!ExtLibUtil.getXspContext().getUser().getRoles().contains("[HR]")) {
     * result = true; } }
     */
    return result;
}
```

}

**ccFieldset**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
>
    <div
        class="form-group"
    >
        <xp:label
            id="label"
            for="input"
            value="${compositeData.label.text}"
        >
            <xp:this.styleClass><![CDATA[${javascript:styleClass = "control-label col-" + compositeData.sz + "-" + compositeData.label.columns;
return styleClass;}]]></xp:this.styleClass>
        </xp:label>
        <xp:div>
            <xp:this.styleClass><![CDATA[${javascript:styleClass = "col-" + compositeData.sz + "-" + compositeData.input.columns;
return styleClass;}]]></xp:this.styleClass>
            <xp:inputText
                id="input"
            >
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[${javascript:"#{"+compositeData.BindTo+"}"}]]></xp:this.value>
                <xp:this.styleClass><![CDATA[${javascript:styleClass = "input-" + compositeData.sz;
return styleClass;}]]></xp:this.styleClass>
            </xp:inputText>
        </xp:div>
    </div>
</xp:view>
```

**Working field in xpage**

```
            <div
            class="form-group"
        >
            <xp:label
                value="Database"
                id="database_Label1"
                for="database1"
                styleClass="col-sm-2 control-label"
            >
            </xp:label>
            <div
                class="col-sm-6"
            >
                <xp:inputText
                    value="#{issue.Database}"
                    id="database1"
                    styleClass="input-sm"
                >
                </xp:inputText>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Not working ccFieldset in xpage**

```
            <xc:fieldset sz="md">
                <xc:this.input>
                    <xc:input
                        columns="10"
                        bindTo="issue.Database"
                    >
                    </xc:input>
                </xc:this.input>
                <xc:this.label>
                    <xc:label
                        columns="2"
                        text="test"
                    >
                    </xc:label>
                </xc:this.label>
            </xc:fieldset>
```

Comment: I never tried what you are attempting, but I would suggest that you try using the Custom binding under 'Advanced'.  You could also try first setting the compositeDate to a scoped variable and then try to dynamically bind the element.

Comment: If you have a normal Java bean with getters and setters then fieldName  has to be "database". It doesn't work with a capital letter as first character. In my tests I had to use "#" instead of "$" in line `value="${compositeData.dsn[compositeData.fieldName]}"`. But, with both changes your code worked for me.

Comment: I've used dynamic bindings in custom controls without any problems using this syntax: `value="#{compositeData.dataSource[compositeData.fieldName]}"`. For an example see here: http://bootstrap4xpages.com/bs4xp/demos.nsf/reusableFields.xsp. BTW: I would never call my field name `Database`, since there's also a global SSJS object called `database`. Theoretically it could work, but I like to stay on the safe side.

Comment: @MarkLeusink I just picked Database because that is a field I already have bound and working the conventional. I will try a different one. Part of the issue may be that the bean I'm using for the back end is using `AbstractDocumentMapModel` and `AbstractMapModel` which @TimTripcony demonstrated on NotesIn9. Maybe without traditional getters and setters for each property, the binding doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The trick is to hand over a String as parameter that would be the EL you want to use. Let's say you have a parameter bindTo as String with the value myBean.Color

```
  <xp:this.value><![CDATA[${javascript:"#{"+compositeData.BindTo+"}"}]]></xp:this.value>
```

The $ will evaluate first and replace the compositeData with the actual value. The beauty of the approach: works for any EL. Document Bean etc., so your custom control doesn't need to make any assumptions on its container.

So you could call your component with all sorts of bindings:

```
 <xc:myComponent BindTo="document1.subject"></xc:myComponent>
 <xc:myComponent BindTo="viewScope.someVariable"></xc:myComponent>
 <xc:myComponent BindTo="myBean.Color"></xc:myComponent>
```

Let us know how that works for you!

Comment: Thank you for the reply. There must be some middle step I'm doing wrong. It appears to be computing to null - the field is non-editable and not populated.

Comment: Add computed fields that show you your parameters, so you see if that works.  And update the question to add your current code attempt.

Comment: What is your parameter value?

Comment: Sorry for the slow response. East coast weather. After I resolved a couple of issues (`compositeData.bindTo` -> `compositeData.input.bindTo` and fixing where I had changed `issue.Database` to lower case as part of my testing) this is working 100%. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that one of the following is true about the object that you're passing to the Custom Control:

1. It really is a bean (specifically, follows [bean conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans#JavaBean_conventions)). For example, if you'll be binding to the `database` property, the object should have (at a minimum) a `getDatabase` method that returns the current value of the `database` property; if the property is not read-only, the class should also have a `setDatabase` method that accepts the new value.
2. It's a [DataObject](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/lotus/Domino-Designer/JavaDocs/DesignerAPIs/com/ibm/xsp/model/DataObject.html): your object implements the `com.ibm.xsp.model.DataObject` interface. The generic `getValue` and `setValue` methods this interface requires you to implement will be used to, respectively, retrieve and update values for any property, including `database`.
3. It's a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). Any property name you bind to will be treated as a key for the map.
4. It's an instance of `com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject`. This is the underlying Java class that all SSJS object literals (`{ }`) become when the SSJS string is parsed at runtime. Be wary of using this type in managed beans, because these objects are not [serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).

As long as the object you're passing in is one of these four, the EL syntax listed in your question will be valid. Set the property type to be either the actual class name for the object you're passing or a base class it extends (or interface it implements). Or, to ensure it will accept anything, just set the property type to `object`.

But remember, declaring a class as a managed bean in the `faces-config.xml` only "manages" a variable name and scope... this declaration doesn't actually make your Java class a bean. Unless it conforms to [bean conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans#JavaBean_conventions), it's not a bean. If it *does* conform to bean conventions, it's a bean, whether or not you declare it as a *managed* bean. This distinction is a source of much confusion in the XPages community, so I just wanted to belabor that again in this context.

Comment: My bean is basically a straight rip from your NotesIn9 presentation, so it conforms with 1,2, and 3. You would recognize the `AbstractDocumentMapModel`. So I have set my type to `<package>.AbstractDocumentMapModel` and since doing that when I compile I get the error _Unknown property dsn. It is not defined on tag xc:input_

Comment: Changing the type to `object` as you suggest fixes the error, but does not actually bind the edit box to my bean.